# Object explorer not loading in SSMS (v18.3.1)

Tags: ssms

Recently have been working on upgrade and fresh installation of SSMS (v18.3.1) on a few servers. Came up on an error where after complete installation of the software object explorer does not load. Checked various posts on stackoverflow and was pointed towards Reset Windows Layout from Windows menu. Unfortunately it failed to fix the issue. A second solution to the problem was to Apply additional key mapping from Tools > Options. Upon opening that noticed an error mentioning : The 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage' package did not load correctly. Reviewed the logs and found that the error was related to : Microsoft Visual Studio Tools. Can anyone assist on this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this issue before publishing the question and here is my solution.

1. Uninstall Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio- 18.3.1 only and not the other related components that have been installed along with it.
2. Go to appwiz.cpl once more after uninstallation of SSMS is been completed and search for Microsoft Visual Studio Tools Application 2017 which is installed along with SSMS (v18.3.1).
3. Click on change and proceed with repair of Microsoft Visual Studio Tools Application 2017.
4. Reinstall SSMS (v18.3.1) and now the object explorer should come up without a hitch.

Hope this helps everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try reassigning the same Drive Letter to each 'missing volume' using Disk Management.  But do not change the drive letter.  Just click the OK button.  When you open File Explorer the 'missing volume' will be in the list of devices.